# C# - Add listviewitem to listview not working

Tags: c#, string, visual-studio, listview, listviewitem

I am seeming to have a problem with adding a listviewitem to a listview. The code that I use doesnt return any exceptions, so I dont know whats wrong. Heres my code:

```
public void addServerToLV(string text)
    {

        string computerName = text.Split('|')[0];
        string userName = text.Split('|')[1];
        string operatingSystem = text.Split('|')[2];
        string ipAddress = text.Split('|')[3];
        string location = text.Split('|')[4];
        string totalRAM = text.Split('|')[5];
        string totalCPU = text.Split('|')[6];
        ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(computerName);
        lvi.SubItems.Add(userName);
        lvi.SubItems.Add(operatingSystem);
        lvi.SubItems.Add(ipAddress);
        lvi.SubItems.Add(location);
        lvi.SubItems.Add(totalRAM);
        lvi.SubItems.Add(totalCPU);
        serversListView.Items.Add(lvi);
    }
```

It seems strange since nothing happens. Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: Do you try to program a rat?

Comment: No, its just a programme that allows other people to view files on a server on a network.

Comment: Did you prepare the ListView? It needs to be set to View=Details __and__ you need to add the Columns you want to show!

Comment: Ive set the view to listview and it has all the columns in the designer. When i put the same code in the Form1_Load method it works fine but it doesnt work in this method.

Comment: Use the debugger to make sure all goes as expected. Where do you call it? - Btw: You really should not split the same string repeatedly! This is not only uneffective but also makes debugging almost impossible! - Do it once and load the item/subitems from the result!

Comment: Why do you add your items as subitems of another item and don't directly add it to your ListView? Or are you trying to do a TreeListView with a ListView?